# How to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I know by definition that a series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges when the sequence of partial sums $S_N=a_1 + a_2 + .. + a_N$ converges to $S$, so $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} S_N=S$.

So in particular, I'm given the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n},$$ which converges to $\ln 2$.

I'm kinda stuck on how to get started. So far I have,

$\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N>0$ s.t. if $n>N$ then $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$.
Is this ok so far? How do I go from here?

Comment: "and I know it converges to 0." It is not true! The series converges to $\ln 2$

Comment: It is true that the terms go to zero, but the partial sums do not go to zero.

Comment: It may help to split the sum into a sum of positive terms and one of negative terms, and show separately that each converges.

Comment: @user99680 Bad luck, this only works for absolutely convergent series, which it is not (you would find that both diverge). You need the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), or use Mike's trick below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your series does not converge to zero - the sequence it sums does, though. (You don't need to prove this, but your series sums to $-\text{ln}(2)$.)

**Hint**: Try grouping successive terms together. In particular, this becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac 1 {2n+1} + \frac 1 {2n+2}\right)$$

See if you can work with that.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So now, I'll have two separate series of evens and odds, I think now I'm stuck on how to prove it using the sequence of partial sums (what I was stuck on before, but I had the series convergence incorrect.)

Comment: Actually, you don't want two separate series. The harmonic series (sum over $1/n$) diverges. Instead, find a simpler way to write this... Hint: $1/n-1/(n+1)=1/(n^2+n)$

Answer (score 2):

Now that you know the answer is $\text{ln}(2)$, perhaps you want to try some kind of estimate using Taylor's Theorem... Note that $\xi>0$ and so $1+\xi > 1$. $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k}-\text{ln}(1+x)| \leq \frac{\frac{n!}{(1+\xi)^n}\cdot x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} < \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

So in our case (it works in all possible values of $x$, since $x$ itself is fixed), we have $x=1$ and hence we have an upper bound of our error of $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Hence, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-x)^k}{k}-\text{ln}(1+x) \rightarrow 0.$$

As for showing the sequence, $[S_{1},S_{2},...$, is convergent, just look at how $S_{1} < S_{3} < ... S_{2n+1}$ and $S_{2} > S_{4} > ... S_{2n}$ and combine to show that $S_{1} < S_{3} < ... S_{2n+1} < S_{2n} < S_{2n-2} < ... S_{4} < S_{2}$. Now, $\forall k,l>2n+1$, $|S_{k}-S_{l}| < S_{2n} - S_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2n}$. So choose $n>\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$ to complete the proof.

**AFTERTHOUGHT:** A subtle point is that I've proven Cauchy and not convergence here; however, in $\mathbb{R}$ they are equivalent so the proof still holds.

Comment: @user12279: does this help?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with Taylor's Theorem. I was trying to I guess prove it from the definition.

Comment: @user12279: Note that Taylor's Theorem is used to prove that the series converges to $ln(2)$, but that is a much stronger statement than what you are probably looking for; that is the series converges. For this see the paragraph afterwards. I give you a proof that works with your definition.

Answer (score 0):

The following lemma (known in some circles as Leibniz's test) trivially solves the problem.

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a monotonic sequence of real numbers converging to $0$. Then the following series
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n $$
>   converges.

I leave out the proof, but it can be found on Wikipedia.